# How to change 25% and 75% quantile line type and color in a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am now dealing with some data and I want to make a boxplot. I notice that I can change the line type and color for the median by setting `medlty` and `medcol`.

I wonder how to change 25% and 75% quantile line type and color in the boxplot? For example, can I set line type 2 and blue for 25% quantile while line type 3 and green for 75% quantile?

```
set.seed(123)
Mydata = sample(x=100:300, size = 500, replace = T)
Mydata = c(Mydata, 1, 500)
boxplot(Mydata,medcol="red", medlty=3)
```

Answer (score -1):

using ggplot from tidyverse. check if it helps!!!

```
library(tidyverse)
Mydata = tibble(dist = sample(x=100:300, size = 500, replace = T))
Mydata %>% ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = dist)) + geom_boxplot()+
  geom_hline(data = quantile(Mydata$dist), yintercept = quantile(Mydata$dist)[2], lty = 2, color = "blue", lwd= 1) +
  geom_hline(data = quantile(Mydata$dist), yintercept = quantile(Mydata$dist)[4], lty = 3, color = "green", lwd = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The blue and green lines are plotted over the original straight lines, which is not what I am asking for. Could you please double check?